# How to group data by a column - Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning Pyspark, I used it to read a csv file into a dataframe:

```
>>> df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv('example.csv')
>>> df.show(n=4)
+-------+------+------+
|main_id|    id| price|
+-------+------+------+
|    100|aaaaa1|190000|
|    101| bbbbb|216000|
|    100|aaaaa2|276000|
|    100|aaaaa3|340000|
+-------+------+------+
only showing top 4 rows
```

How can I group data based on the first column `main_id` and group the `id` and `price` in an array, then convert the dataframe to a newline delimited json format? Something like:

```
{"main_id": "100", "items": [{"id": "aaaaa1", "price": 190000},{"id": "aaaaa2", "price": 276000},{"id": "aaaaa3", "price": 340000}]}
{"main_id": "101", "id": "bbbbb", "price": 216000}
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `struct` and `groupby` with `collect_list` as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df1.select(f.col("main_id"), f.struct(f.col("id"), f.struct("price")).alias("items"))\
    .groupby("main_id")\
    .agg(f.collect_list("items").alias("items"))
```

Or:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df1.groupby("main_id") \
    .agg(f.collect_list("id").alias("id"), f.collect_list("price").alias("price"))\
    .select("main_id", f.arrays_zip(f.col("id"), f.col("price")).alias("items"))
```

Output:

```
{"main_id":100,"items":[{"id":"aaaaa1","col2":{"price":190000}},{"id":"aaaaa2","col2":{"price":276000}},{"id":"aaaaa3","col2":{"price":340000}}]}
{"main_id":101,"items":[{"id":"bbbbb","col2":{"price":216000}}]}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, just wondering what does `f` mean in the code? I didn't see the definition of `f`..

Comment: Ahh do you mean `from pyspark.sql import functions as f`? But the last line `.select("main_id", f.arrays_zip(f.col("id"), f.col("price")).alias("items"))` threw an error saying `AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'arrays_zip'`.

Comment: Yes exactly it is from `from pyspark.sql import functions as f`

Comment: Make sure you have `Spark Version is 2.4.0+`  to be able to use `arrays_zip`

Comment: Aww right I'm using 2.3, makes sense, thanks.